# Error importing a storybook component into a generic react app

Tags: reactjs, jsx, storybook

I have two npm projects:

1. A storybook project with my own design system components
2. A generic react+redux application, where i want to use the storybook components

These are the files and code in the storybook project

[image]

```
// index.js
export { default as GnButton } from './stories/Button';
```

This is the code in the application where i want to use this button component:

```
import { GnButton } from 'genesis-ds'
```

This is the error when compiling:
[image]

It cannot handle well the jsx of external packages, but it does handle well the jsx of its own components.
What i have to do?